# How to start NodeJS app from bash with file permissions

Tags: node.js, bash, raspberry-pi

I have built a NodeJS application that is running on a Raspberry Pi.

The app runs a child_process: raspistill, which captures an image using the Raspberry Pi camera module and writes it to a file.

The node app then watches for changes in that file.

If I start the node app from the terminal manually, I have no problems, but if I start it from a bash script (/etc/rc.local) when the Pi starts up, it doesn't work.

I'm unsure as to exactly what is going wrong, but I guess that it is because it does not have permissions to write the file to disk because I see the red camera light turn on and then nothing.

So the question is how can I enable the app to write to disk after being started from the rc.local script?

Comment: Would be helpful if you included the script...

Comment: The issue might be that you use a relative path to access the file, while the current directory is not the one your script is in. Try using `__dirname`: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Answer (score 0):

Rather than launching your Node application with /etc/rc.local, you might want to use Cron's `@reboot` target instead, and launch Node within a GNU Screen session.  You'd use a crontab something like this:

```
@reboot screen -h 5000 -d -m /path/to/nodewrapper.sh
```

where nodewrapper.sh sets up your environment variables and launches Node.

The advantages here include that:

- you can see debug output from Node in Screen's history, and
- you get to run commands using an environment (yours) that you know works.

With the debug output from Node, you may see an error that makes your *actual* problem obvious.

Note that [TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).  I don't claim that way this is best, just that it works for me.